# Is there a standard pronunciation for gender-neutral -@ or -x

Tags: pronunciation, loanwords, gender-neutral, spanish

More and more I see, especially in activist communities, Spanish-derived words ending in x or @ in order to neuter the gendering inherent in the original language. For example: latinx (or latin@) as opposed to latina and latino.

How, though, are these endings pronounced? Please provide evidence of how this orthography is most commonly pronounced.

Note 1: I recognize this is in an English Language site, rather than a Spanish language site, but this phenomenon is very much happening in English, albeit with Spanish loan words. Therefore the question is relevant to non-Spanish-speaking English speakers.

Note 2: A question like this can lead to politically charged or, at least, sarcastic comments. Please refrain from bringing in your biases for or against.

Note 3: This question is not seeking *opinions* as to how some people pronounce the suffixes. Answers should address *evidence of a developing orthodoxy* in pronunciation.

Comment: Rather more fundamental than that, how do you intend to address someone if *he* and *she* are equally taboo?

Comment: It's like a joke, so with a smile... :-)

Comment: @RMac From my experience, though, this site leans pretty descriptivist. If people are using something, that something deserves being looked at

Comment: Definitely on topic for ELU, but might be helped by knowing what they do in Spanish.

Comment: This is essentially [a matter of opinion](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/why-people-are-using-the-term-latinx_us_57753328e4b0cc0fa136a159). But I've no doubt that people will quite naturally enunciate it as **latinEX**, since that's what it *looks* like. I don't expect many of them think of it as punning on **-esque** as a suffix (via AAVE ***ask = aks**!* :)

Comment: @Unrelated This site can lean toward descriptive evaluation slightly, but if it turns completely toward description, the purpose of the site collapses, since the concepts of "correct" and "incorrect" disappear entirely. This question lands rather past the line between "answerable question" and "new idiosyncratic thing" and I'm afraid as a result no one person can offer a true *answer*, apart, I mean, from one's own opinion. We have to wait for English speakers collectively to decide the right way to do it--or, maybe better, not to do it at all. ;)

Comment: @RMac That may be but that doesn't deserve it's being called a silly phenomenon or for the rejection of a writer's attempts. It may not have an answer yet but that does not deny that it is a phenomenon. I don't refuse a claim that this is off-topic (though Mitch argues otherwise), but I do object to your declaring it silly when it is very much a real occurrence.

Comment: The question that is actually answerable is "how are these endings commonly pronounced when read aloud". As currently posed, this question is attracting inventive but not very useful answers to "how *should* these endings be pronounced".

Comment: @MetaEd You are right. That is the question I thought I was asking.

Comment: Lol. So crazy activists are trying to ruin Spanish too. That's funny.

Comment: Someone who speaks with the intention to be understood and heard wouldn't normally pronounce words that do not exist in spoken language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: This is not an opinion-based question at all. This is a closed-form question ("How is ___ commonly pronounced?"), which is well-accepted by this site. It even has its own tag. There is a definite answer. Please re-open the question or rescind your vote, or explain what you mean. (Perhaps the question was edited since you closed it.)

Comment: @jvriesem: Do you *seriously* think there's a "definitive answer" to how people pronounce such an unusual neologism? One person might cite [oxforddictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/Latinx), but that hardly invalidates ['Latin@' Offers A Gender-Neutral Choice; But How To Pronounce It?](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2013/01/07/168818064/latin-offers-a-gender-neutral-choice-but-how-to-pronounce-it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: There *is* a definitive pronunciation for "latinx", and that's half the question. I don't think there's a *consensus* for to how to pronounce "latin@" yet, but there may be in the near future. That doesn't make this an opinion-based question. It's just that half of this question doesn't have an answer *yet*. You could counter by saying that while it is a closed-form question, it encourages opinion-based *answers*, but that's a topic for Meta.

Comment: @jvriesem: I don't think there's even a consensus on how to pronounce "marital-status neutral" **Ms** yet (I hear it with a schwa or /ɪ/ about equally often, and would probably be inconsistent *myself* if I actually used the term). Surely questions asking *What's the **most common** way of pronouncing X?* are almost *by definition* subjective. It's often possible today to use Internet searches to establish more or less definitively how people *write* many words - but how they *say* them? If people disagree, who's to say who's right?

Comment: @FumbleFingers People are always claiming this is a site for linguists, especially when trying to shun the single word request crowd. Pronunciation is certainly in the purview of linguists, even when it is new. Sociolinguists are always tracking how language and pronunciation is changing. Whether or not you have an answer to the question does not mean this question isn't legitimate.

Comment: @jvriesem: I'd say in matters of pronunciation, linguists are probably getting left behind by AI speech recognition (which so far as I know simply reflects what people say, not what experts *think* they should say). Using Google voice input on my smartphone to ask *What is **latinEX / latinKS*** in both cases results in the voice ***output*** saying the latter (two-syllable) form. But when I ask about ***latinAT*** I can't get it to consider the ***@*** character - when I can get it to recognise what I say as a single word, it's only ever ***latinate***. Make of that what you will.

Comment: I've made a further edit to emphasise that this question is legitimately asking for evidence of *standard* or *most common* pronunciation of these suffixes, and to reduce the impression that it's seeking *personal opinion*. I've also added my vote to reopen the question, which I think is both on-topic and a good one. :-)

Answer (score 7):

I first encountered this in Costa Rica in the 1990s!  (It was not widespread at the time, but it was in use in at least some activist organisations promoting gender equality.)  As far as I can recall, I don't think there was a way of pronouncing it, it was simply a way of shortening one's writing.  You could write "amig@s", but you would still have to say "amigas y amigos".

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/word-history-latinx) (in a blog) says to pronounce the "x" in "latinx" as "ex", and they give the pronunciation as "\luh-TEE-neks" which in IPA would be something like /lə'ti neks/. [Cambridge has voice samples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/latinx) that are similar.